# i have to get records which must always contain two ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

from the given table data i only want all the date of ticketid which must have status id 2 and 5. if a ticket does not have statusid 2 or 5 i do not need it

the query i am using,

```
select *
from MISTicketDetail
where createdDate in (select createdDate
                      from MISTicketDetail
                      where StatusId > 1)
order by ticketId asc;
```

table data

```
id, date, tickedid, statusid  
1   2019-07-20 17:54:20.320 1   1
2   2019-07-20 17:54:37.590 1   2
3   2019-07-20 17:54:54.973 1   3
4   2019-07-20 17:55:15.127 1   2
5   2019-07-20 17:55:29.040 1   5
6   2019-07-20 17:56:22.090 1   5
7   2019-07-20 17:59:36.667 2   1
8   2019-07-20 17:59:48.937 3   1
9   2019-07-20 18:00:09.617 4   2
10  2019-07-20 18:00:15.890 4   4
11  2019-07-20 18:00:23.640 4   3
12  2019-07-20 18:00:40.987 4   5
13  2019-07-20 18:00:58.720 4   2
14  2019-07-20 18:01:30.520 5   1
15  2019-07-20 18:01:41.673 5   3
16  2019-07-20 18:01:49.970 5   5
17  2019-07-20 18:02:05.333 6   1
18  2019-07-20 18:02:12.130 6   2
19  2019-07-20 18:02:26.860 6   5
20  2019-07-20 18:02:34.553 6   2
21  2019-07-20 18:02:43.503 6   3
22  2019-07-20 18:02:56.857 6   2
23  2019-07-20 18:03:03.380 6   5
```

result required is below

```
id, date, tickedid, statusid     
2   2019-07-20 17:54:37.590     1   2
3   2019-07-20 17:54:54.973     1   3
4   2019-07-20 17:55:15.127     1   2
5   2019-07-20 17:55:29.040     1   5
6   2019-07-20 17:56:22.090     1   5
9   2019-07-20 18:00:09.617     4   2
10  2019-07-20 18:00:15.890     4   4
11  2019-07-20 18:00:23.640     4   3
12  2019-07-20 18:00:40.987     4   5
13  2019-07-20 18:00:58.720     4   2
18  2019-07-20 18:02:12.130     6   2
19  2019-07-20 18:02:26.860     6   5
20  2019-07-20 18:02:34.553     6   2
21  2019-07-20 18:02:43.503     6   3
22  2019-07-20 18:02:56.857     6   2
23  2019-07-20 18:03:03.380     6   5
```

Comment: So, what is your question here?

Comment: just updated my question. with result that i want

Comment: Sounds like you need an `EXISTS`.

Comment: how to use an exists?? any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `group by ticketId` to get the `ticketId`s that have rows with `statusid` `2` **and** `5` and use this result to return the rows of the table:

```
select * from 
MISTicketDetail 
where ticketId in (
  select ticketId from MISTicketDetail 
  where StatusId in (2, 5)
  group by ticketId
  having count(distinct StatusId) = 2
) 
order by id, ticketId;
```

From your sample data I guess that you don't need `distinct` but I used it just in case.

Comment: thanks a lot it works fine except i added greater than 
having count(distinct StatusId) > 1

Comment: Do you mean `count(distinct StatusId) > 2`? If you did this it is wrong.

Comment: No it is not, if you want both 2 and 5 you must use `having count(distinct StatusId) = 2`.

Comment: But if you want only 1 of 2 or 5 then > 0 is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
select date from table_name where statusid=2 or statusid=5
```

Comment: i want the other status ids in between these as well only when these two are there

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an [`EXISTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) would work here:

```
SELECT {Your Columns}
FROM MISTicketDetail TD
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM MISTicketDetail e
              WHERE e.ticketid = TD.ticketid
                AND e.statusid IN (2,5));
```

Comment: the result still brings ticketid without statusid 2

Comment: i meant count of 2 and 5 must be greater than 1, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
where StatusId in (2,5)
```

instead of

```
where StatusId > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We could try using `COUNT` here as an analytic function:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN statusid = 2 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ticketid) cnt_2,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN statusid = 5 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ticketid) cnt_5
    FROM MISTicketDetail
)

SELECT id, date, ticketid, statusid
FROM cte
WHERE cnt_2 > 0 AND cnt_5 > 0;
```

[image]

### Demo